# Jenkins pipeline throwing CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required error for mysql connection

Tags: mysql, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I was trying to establish connection to mysql database, using Jenkins pipeline and when do that I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

MySQL db version is **5.1.73** 
For the same database when I use **mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar** in a Java program I was able to establish connection. But for the version below , higher or the same mysql-connectors I was not able to connect using Jenkins pipeline.

I searched internet and was not able to find a solution. Version compatibility was always mentioned as problem in some posts for this error trace in Java.

Plugins used in Jenkins are **database** & **database-mysql**

Here's my pipeline script

```
  import groovy.sql.Sql
  node{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
     dbConnection = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "password","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
}
```